# Is there a way to search among all of my questions from all sites?

Tags: support, search

I know I can see all of my questions from all sites. But I can't search among all the questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no built-in option for that in the [networkwide search](https://stackexchange.com/search), so you'd need a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1110458/search-within-questions-by-a-single-user-networkwide) for that. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1110482/networkwide-search-template) is another one which searches all posts.

It requires your global account ID which you can find [on your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) in the address bar.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1110458/search-within-questions-by-a-single-user-networkwide?AccountId=7923772&query=difference) are the results for your user and a common word *in questions only*:

[image]

Please note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, so the results may be a little bit outdated.