# Cross Stack Exchange search through all of my questions?

Tags: feature-request, search, stack-exchange, elasticsearch, global-search

I struggled with finding my own question that finally was on StackOverflow. First, I had checked Unix & Linux, then AskUbuntu, then SuperUser.

I will not be the only one with that problem, there is some need for a cross Stack Exchange search through all of a user's questions.

I have found two similar feature requests:

- [Search/browse my own questions easily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13424/search-browse-my-own-questions-easily), 10 upvotes, 11 years old, 279 views, *"status-completed" tag*.
- [cross Stack Exchange search of all my favorited questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209132/cross-stack-exchange-search-of-all-my-favorited-questions) has 4 upvotes, 7 years old, 63 views. This should be technically the same thing.

[How can I view all my unaccepted questions across SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119575/how-can-i-view-all-my-unaccepted-questions-across-se) is the SEDE solution, which could be a workaround as well for this feature request here, I would like to know the SEDE that would work like this feature request. But better would be a new user filter in the cross Stack Exchange search.

It should work like this:

[image]

The `is:question` filter works ([here is the link](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=docker+user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion)):

[image]

Comment: Fun bit: `user:me` doesn't work but [`user:811` does work](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A811+is%3Aq+account) and that is only because Shog9 has the same userid on many sites. Atwood has 1 ....

Comment: [Is there a way to search among all of my questions from all sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333562/295232) – it turns out that I already wrote a query for exactly that. (I'm not using my dupehammer; this is a feature request, that is a support question.)

Comment: @Glorfindel I still should have found it, I am lucky that it was "support" tagged.

Comment: *I* should have found it before answering your question :)

Comment: @Glorfindel I would say your answer is needed in both places. The SEDE query is like a first prototype of the feature. "It turns out that I already wrote a query exactly for that". That is the right 100K meta member! :) Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've written a [network-wide search template SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1110482/networkwide-search-template) a while ago. You might want to give it a try. It searches through questions, answers *and* comments; feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/1110482) it and adapt it to your needs.

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1110482/networkwide-search-template?AccountId=15462527&query=java) shows your posts and comments across the network containing the word 'java'.

[image]

Comment: Great. works, but: loading time was > 1 min. That is perhaps the reason why it has not been put in the cross Stack Exchange search?

Comment: Stack Exchange search is based on Elastic, which is faster than SQL for this kind of thing. Parallelization may also play a role.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the elasticsearch tag.